# IoT возможно ли подключиться к умной лампочке с помощью python скрипта?

Tags: python

Если возможно, скиньте пример или ссылку.

Начинаю постигать мир IoT. Интересно написать платформу, для работы с умными устройствами, самостоятельно. Возможно ли это? Или может есть вариант подключиться не к реальным устройствами, а эмулятору?

Comment: можно. эмуляторов не видел, но если будут - поделитесь)

Comment: @eri а что по Вашему нужно эмулировать в iot устройстве? чем это отличается от обычных запросов к http серверу и ответам от него?

Comment: Всё зависит от поддерживаемых лампочкой протоколов, читайте документацию к ней

Comment: @StrangerintheQ http то наснифить и работай сразу, а вот modbus, dmx, artnet... попробуй разберись где яркость, а где цвет. да и не покупать же десяток лампочек для разработки

Comment: @eri если говорить про конретные модели - понятно что вам ни кто не даст наружу кишки проприетарных протоколов/серверов в виде эмуляторов или еще чего-то, потом у некоторых представителей часть логики убрана с устройств в облака. имхо тут может быть речь про создание эмулятора к своему iot устройству

Comment: с другой стороны какраз могут дать такие эмуляторы, что производитель потом использовал их устройства.

Comment: да и artnet не такой уж и проприетарный)

Comment: "возможно ли подключиться к умной лампочке с помощью python скрипта?" - в локальной сети легко. Из внешней сети - или у вас должен быть открыт какой-то порт на роутере во внешний интернет (что не есть хорошо), или должен быть какой-то внешний сервис, к которому лампочка периодически подключается, и смотрит, в каком состоянии ей нужно находиться.